# How to use MemberQ for such Variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

This is *NOT* the desired out come. I want this test to fail:

```
pars = Table[ Subscript[\[Tau], ToExpression[ToString[\[Phi]] <> ToString@j]], {j, 5}]
MemberQ[pars, Subscript[\[Tau], p_]]
(* True *)
```

This *is* the desired out come. I want this test to pass:

```
pars2 = Table[ Subscript[\[Tau], ToExpression["p" <> ToString@j]], {j, 5}]
MemberQ[pars2, Subscript[\[Tau], p_]]
(* True *)
```

Why did the first `MemberQ` test returns `True`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `p_` simply means a pattern (`Blank[]`) that you want to name `p`. Normally this (giving it a name) is done because you want to do something with the matched pattern. The point here is that you are **not** testing for a subscripted variable that starts with `p`. You code is essentially equivalent to `MemberQ[pars2, Subscript[\[Tau], _]]` which is why you get `True` for both.

If you want to distinguish `p` from `\[Phi]` then add a condition to your test:

```
MemberQ[pars, Subscript[\[Tau], z_ /; StringTake[ToString[z], 1] === "p"]]
```

Although it is probably even easier just to use strings as subscripts and save your self the trouble of converting back to string for the condition test.